# How to add a package to unattended-upgrades?

Tags: updates, unattended-upgrades

How to add a package to unattended-upgrades to be automatically updated ? For exemple, add the application named XXX to unattended-upgrades in order to be updated in background.

Comment: I don't have brave installed and I'm not going to do so, so I can't try it out. [Here](https://linux-audit.com/upgrading-external-packages-with-unattended-upgrade/) is a guide which demonstrates with an example how to add a ppa to unattended-upgrades.

Comment: The snap firefox updates automatically in background

Comment: I removed "firefox" as I don't ask for automatically update firefox

Comment: You cannot add a single package. You can add a repository.